# Auto-generated sitemap.xml on 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, sitemaps, crontab

I have a problem with the auto-generation of my sitemap. I did everything I have written below.

1. I created a sitemap through *Admin > Catalog > Google Sitemap* option
2. I made the auto-generation setup *Admin > System > Configuration > Catalog > Google Sitemap > Generation Settings*
3. I added crontab a cron job for `cron.sh` (This cron job runs every hour / I have evidence that it works)

But the auto-generation still does not work! Is there any log files I can check? I don't know what's missing!

Comment: Have you set your sitemap to generate every hour? Usually it's once a day. Can you add your screenshot?

Comment: Magento's cron.sh runs every hour. The setup for the sitemap.xml is once a day at 00:05.

Comment: You have to wait till next day then. Or is it you have already waited 1 day.

Comment: Yes I did. The sitemap.xml job setup is for 00:05. But I created a sitemap through Admin > Catalog > Google Sitemap option in the daytime manually / by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using n98 to view the cron history and confirm its not being missed , you can also use it to run the manually and confirm it works - https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

And change the cron.sh to run every minute or at least every 5.

Comment: I changed the cron.sh schedule to every 5 minutes.  Cron job started to  generate the sitemap.xml. Thanks for the advice...

Comment: glad that worked usually you want to do it every minute with cron.sh, as it will check to see if cron.php is still running and do nothing if it is, so that way nothing is missed.